# How to read characters from fifo file with kotlin

Tags: java, linux, kotlin, udev

**What I am trying to do**:
I am trying to make a combination between Linux udev and Kotlin. More exactly when I plug in a USB into my PC one of the rules from udev will launch a script that will append to a FIFO file some text. (Like: add,003,026. Where 003 is the bus number and the 026 is the device number).
Now on the Kotlin side, I intend to read this information and show it to the IDE console. All good here.

**My problem**:
When I receive only one event due to only one plugin everything is ok. But when I try to plug in multiple devices ( by pressing the power button on a hub with 7 devices connected ) I usually receive only 3 devices on the Kotlin side. Even if the FIFO file has all the values.

**Sample code**
Here is my last try of gaining all the information

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, World")
    while(true) {
        println("I had received this: " + readUsbState())
        //println("Am primit inapoi: " + ins.read())
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1L)
    }
}

@Throws(FileNotFoundException::class)
private fun readUsbState(): String {
    if (!File("/emy/usb_events").exists()) {
        throw FileNotFoundException("The file /emy/usb_events doesn't exists!")
    }
    val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    var byteRead = 0
    val bytesArray = ByteArray(1024)
    try {
        FileInputStream("/emy/usb_events").use { inputStream ->
            byteRead = inputStream.read(bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.size)
            if (byteRead >= 0) {
                bytes.write(bytesArray, 0, byteRead)
            }
        }
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
    return bytes.toString()
}
```

**More instructions**:
My fifo file is "/emy/usb_events". This file was created with mkfifo /emy/usb_events

and for the testing part to don't bother with the udev rules you can simply make echo -e "add,001,001\nadd,001,002\nadd,001,003\n..." >> /emy/usb_events

Answer (score 0):

I have found the correct answer. 
The problem was that I was closing the FIFO file after the first enter that was found. The below code works perfectly:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, World")
    while(true) {
        println("I had received this: " + readUsbState4())
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1L)
    }
}

private fun readUsbState4(): String {
    return File("/certus/usb_events").readLines(Charset.defaultCharset()).toString()
}
```

In the list that I am receiving, I may have multiple pieces of information like:

```
Hello, World
I had received this: [add,046,003,4-Port_USB_2.0_Hub,Generic,]
I had received this: [add,048,003,Android_Phone,FA696BN00557,HTC, add,047,003,4-Port_USB_2.0_Hub,Generic,, add,049,003,DataTraveler_2.0,001BFC31A1C7C161D9C75AED,Kingston]
I had received this: [add,050,003,SAMSUNG_Android,06157df6cc9ac70e,SAMSUNG, add,053,003,SAMSUNG_Android,ce0416046d6a9e3f05,SAMSUNG, add,051,003,Acer_S57,0123456789ABCDEF,MediaTek, add,052,003,ACER_Z160,SKU4HI8L4L99N76H,MediaTek]
I had received this: [remove,048,003]
I had received this: [remove,051,003, remove,052,003, remove,049,003, remove,053,003, remove,050,003]
I had received this: [remove,047,003]
I had received this: [remove,046,003]
```